# Simple installation from source on Linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, installation

I'm trying to figure out a simplified way for installing C and C++ code
and libraries built from them,  primarily for Linux.  I *think* GNU Autotools,  CMake,  etc. would be overkill for what I'm trying to do.

An example:  I've written some code which,  when 'make' is run,  builds to
create a library 'example.a'.  (I'm going with static linking thus far.
Shared libraries will introduce still more issues;  I'll crawl before I walk.)  Use of the functions requires including 'example1.h', 'example2.h',  etc.

With Autotools,  one would run 'make install' or 'sudo make install' to
copy example.a to /usr/local/lib and the include files to /usr/local/include.
If executables had been built,  those would get copied to /usr/local/bin.

I've tried adding the following lines to my makefile:

install:
    cp example.a /usr/local/lib
    cp example1.h /usr/local/include
    cp example2.h /usr/local/include
    cp example /usr/local/bin

This seems to work,  mostly.  Other projects are then able to "see"
the .h files and build correctly.  But the .a file is not found;  the only
way to get it to be linked is to explicitly give the path as
/usr/local/lib/example.a.   (Though gcc insists it's looking for libraries
in that path.)  So:

Question 1:  Should my user-built libraries be put in /usr/local/lib?  Or am
I using the wrong directory?

Now,  my next problem:  this has to be done with 'sudo make install'.
I'm thinking that for some projects of this ilk,  where only one user will
be making use of the code in question,  the libraries should go someplace
such as $HOME/lib,  include files to $HOME/include,  executables to
$HOME/bin.

Question 2:  Is there a "standard" way to install includes/libraries for
just the current user,  rather than doing so for all users?  (Thus avoiding
the need for root use,  and I'd think it would be a "cleaner" system if only
the user using the program had to deal with these files.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use `install` to copy with explicit permissions. `example.a` probably isn't being found because it doesn't start with lib (a stupid requirement, I know).

Putting your `lib`, `include`, and `bin` under `$HOME/`.local is probably the closest thing to a per-user standard setup.

**Edit:**

I just tested it and it `/usr/local/lib` works fine for me:

**foo.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo() { puts("foo"); }
```

Compile and install:

```
gcc -c foo.c
ar crs libfoo.a foo.o
install -m 0755 /usr/local/lib #0644 should do too
```

In a different directory:

**main.c**

```
void foo(void);
int main() { foo(); return 0; }
```

Compile, link, and run:

```
gcc main.c -lfoo 
./a.out
```

Comment: Thank you.  Hadn't heard of 'install',  but 'man install' brings me up to speed.  Renaming to 'libexample.a' didn't help;  I'll continue to investigate.  Your suggestion for a per-user setup seems reasonable, though I do find it odd that there isn't a more "standard" way of doing this... surely I'm not the first to run into this situation?

Comment: Ah,  I see where I goofed (and 'man ld' and looking at the -l option confirms this):  the file must be named 'libfoo.a'.  One can then use either '-lfoo',  and ld will tack the lib in front and .a after it.  _Or_ you can use '-l:libfoo.a',  and it'll treat it literally.  Thanks again;  this was quite baffling...

Comment: Nice. I didn't know about `:`. Too bad I can't seem to be able to get it to work for shared libraries where I could really use it (only for static ones).